# Windows 8 - automatic repair loop :(

Tags: windows-8, boot, system-restore

I know that this problem has been reported many times before, BUT so far there has not been a single solution.

So yesterday, I switched off my pc from the main plug (windows 8 32bit pro), today when I get up I see automatic repair and pc diagnosis popping up, it moved onto checking my drive in the boot up w8 screen. After about 2 hours I got annoyed since I had to some work so I turned off my pc from the main socket again. This time only when I reboot, automatic repair comes up and then a blue screen saying "Automatic repair couldnt repair your pc" with a log file called srttrail.txt.

I can move onto advanced options and I have tried the following:
- System restore (no restore points)
- System refresh
- Start up settings
- Automatic repair

I have rebooted the pc over 10 times without success. And now I really need your help guys, because the only option that I can back myself upon is CMD.

Thank you very much in advance

### Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log

Last successful boot time: ‎4/‎17/‎2013 1:57:48 PM (GMT)
Number of repair attempts: 13

### Session details

System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0
Windows directory = D:\Windows
AutoChk Run = 0
Number of root causes = 1

### Test Performed:

Name: Check for updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System disk test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk failure diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 93 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 32 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Target OS test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 62 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Volume content check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 250 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Boot manager diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System boot log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Event log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 141 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Internal state check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 31 ms

### Root cause found:

Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem.

### ---------------------------

### Session details

System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0
Windows directory = D:\Windows
AutoChk Run = 0
Number of root causes = 1

### Test Performed:

Name: Check for updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System disk test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk failure diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 93 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 32 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Target OS test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 62 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Volume content check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 297 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Boot manager diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System boot log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Event log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 156 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Internal state check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 31 ms

### Root cause found:

Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem.

### ---------------------------

### Session details

System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0
Windows directory = D:\Windows
AutoChk Run = 0
Number of root causes = 1

### Test Performed:

Name: Check for updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System disk test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk failure diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 78 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 31 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Target OS test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 62 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Volume content check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 266 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Boot manager diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: System boot log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 16 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Event log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 156 ms

### Test Performed:

Name: Internal state check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 31 ms

### Root cause found:

Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem.

### ---------------------------

Comment: Your own actions have likely corrupted your Windows installation beyond repair.  Post the contents of srttrail.txt if you want any hope of getting help.

Comment: Your installation is corrupted beyond repair.

Comment: Perfect! Anyway I can recover all my files before formatting?? Thanks ;)

Comment: Try a Linux LiveCD/USB for data recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Find a hiren's bootCD and boot from it. Use min Windows xp.

That should open at least the drive for you so you can copy to a USB. Be sure you put your backup USB drive in before you boot from the CD so the CD can see it then you can backup to it.